# I want to implement one time registration screen in android using shared preferences but i'm not able to get the previous shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i want to retrieve the previously stored shared preferences. i have implemented the second activity. i want that user enter the data only one time

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sp = this.getSharedPreferences(TEXT_VALUE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    completed = sp.getBoolean(TEXT_VALUE_KEY, false);

    if (completed == true) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, Welcome.class);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User Already Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } 

    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_number);
    btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Register_Button);






}
```

Comment: How have you saved the previous shared preferences? Please post code. Also make a toast when the completed == false.

Comment: @Perroloco: i want to get the previously stored shared preferences.

Comment: @dhaval.s: here's the code to save the data

sp = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(REG_ID, regId);
editor.commit();
finsih();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not saving and retrieve the shared preferences right. To save preference try this, its simpler.

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( this);
Editor edit = sp.edit();
edit.putBoolean("completed",x);
//You can put more objects
edit.commit();
```

To get shared preferences,

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences.(this);
boolean completed = sp.getBoolean("completed",false);
```

Also you are putting string and trying to get boolean.

Comment: i have tried this method but the problem is i'm getting the previous activity. i want that once user register the app the next activity should be displayed

Comment: So at the registration activity, once you store user's data, put a boolean with value "true" in the preference. Then check at the start of the registration activity, load the preference and check if(boolean == true). If true, start the second activity via an intent. If you see in the above answer, the default value of boolean is false if it doesn't exist. So your code will run fine.

Comment: yeah i have put boolean at the end but still not getting any previous data. when i go to manage apps-setting-myapp it shows that i have saved some amount of data

Comment: How do you know that you are not getting any value? And what do you mean by previous data? If your device is rooted, try going in /data/data/[your package name]/shared_prefs/ and open the file present in it and see if any data has been stored, if yes what is its value. Also you can place a break point just after you load the preferences and debug your app. This will stop after you have stored the value of boolean in a variable. Then see what is the value stored in it.